# Gulp and TS compilation

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have defined task in my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('dev:build:scripts', function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));
});
```

Which takes all of the scripts, and creates source maps to the `static/dist`. My tsProject:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    outDir: paths.dist +'/app'
});
```

And my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "static/dist/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

However, after the gulp runs the project, it doesnt compile the JS and doesnt create sourcemaps - it only does so, when I make a change to any ts file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to actually write your results. Try this one:

```
gulp.task('dev:build:scripts', () => 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));  

    return tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist +'/app'));        
});
```

Comment: that was it :) thanks! do you know if it is possible to run npm install as a gulp task?

Comment: Like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec or this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell ?