# Grunt duplicate errors typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gruntjs

I am very new to TypeScript and have just been setting up a project with Grunt. When compiling I receive a large amount duplicate errors in relation to the TypeScript grunt-typescript folder. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
 Bens-MacBook-Pro:Chapter1 bendavies$ Grunt
 Running "watch" task
 Waiting...
 >> File "app.ts" changed.
 Running "typescript:base" (typescript) task
 >> node_modules/grunt-typescript/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.core.d.ts(83,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'configurable'.
```

This is just a subset of the errors, but they all seem to be duplicate related!

Cheers!

Here is my tsconfig.json file if that's any help!

```
 {
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "tasks",
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "diagnostics": true,
    "noLib": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
},
"files": [
    "src/index.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.core.d.ts",
    "typings/lib.support.d.ts"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/**"
]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by modifying the GruntFile.js to a more specific set of sources. Here is the GruntFile I am using now!

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    typescript: {
        base: {
            src: ['*.ts'],
            options:{
                module: 'commonjs',
                target: 'ea5',
                sourceMap: true

            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files: '*.ts',
        tasks: ['typescript']

    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not included your tsconfig.json - I might guess that you missed to exclude node_modules folder.

Try with 'exclude' section set like in the sample below:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "bin",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser/**"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi I gave this a go but it still produces the error! I've added my tsconfig.json file if you could please give that a look over!

Comment: you do not need 'files' section. try without it.

Comment: tsc automatically include lib.core.d.ts. And lib.support.d.ts will be included as it is not explicitly excluded

Comment: Unfortunately get the same problem! Also tried deleting the troublesome libraries but then it complains about not finding variables, can't win! haha!

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you build without grunt with pure tsc? You can also try to setup build using gulp (gulp task will be somewhat like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956888/gulp-and-ts-compilation/35957118#35957118) and see if error will persist. If you do not get the errors - then its an issue with your grunt config/setup.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it! It turns out within the GruntFile.js I had the src ambiguously set to all ts files! Only allowing it to seek out files within a single folder seems to have resolved it! Cheers for your help!